# Activity not found exception android studio

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio

I was doing a project in android using android studio. It was all working perfectly. Then I made a little edits in the `MainActivity.java` edits means, between two runs all I did was adding a function in `onCreate()` method. But when I tried to run it, the app crashed. I commented the line which i wrote and ran again, but it still crashed. So I tried debugging by adding an exception break point. And the exception break point hit the following line in the `Class.class` file:

```
public static java.lang.Class<?> forName(java.lang.String className, boolean shouldInitialize, java.lang.ClassLoader classLoader) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException { /* compiled code */ }
```

The exception details are shown below:

```
Exception = {java.lang.ClassNotFoundException@3344}
    ex = {java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class "Lcom/personal/myproject/MainActivity;" not found}
    cause = {java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.personal.myproject.MainActivity}
    detailMessage = {com.personal.myproject.MainActivity}
```

It happened all of a sudden. As I said, the only change that I added between two program runs is adding a single line of code, calling a single function in MainActivity's `onCreate()`. And now even after commenting that off, it doesn't make a difference, still throwing the exception.
Yes I have MainActivity defined in the manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Anyone has got any idea?

Comment: Already tried. Same effect. Cleaned and even tried rebuild.

Comment: seems got something wrong in here: Lcom/personal/myproject/MainActivity; and com.personal.myproject.MainActivity

Comment: Can you post the content of the onCreate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this issue solved partially. Actually I was having this issue when running in debug mode only. The app ran perfectly if I just run it, not in debug mode. However, even in debug mode, if I just run the app, by not setting the exception breakpoint, it just runs. However, if I set the exception breakpoint, it still has the issue of hitting the `Class Not Found Exception`, and I still can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the fully qualified name of the Activity (package + class name) to the AndroidManifest.xml

or make sure the Activity sits on the main application package, the one declared in the AndroidManifest **packageName**.

Comment: The path was correct, yet I gave the full path, still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue until I realized that the app *is* running -- it's just hitting a ClassNotFound exception early in its execution. You should be able to hit continue and the app will run. I found that my particular app hit dozens of exception breakpoints before settling on the MainActivity.

One trick here is to not enable the exception breakpoint until after another breakpoint is hit in your app. This can be done from the Breakpoints screen (shift-apple-F8 in Android Studio/IntelliJ). I would suggest setting the exception breakpoints to start after something interesting (as you define interesting) happens.